# Upload image to amazon s3 with phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload image directly to s3 bucket from my phonegap application.

I'm doing following the steps in amazon documentation, but it still returns me errors. 
Amazon credentials are right, I've checked it. Also I've set CORS permissions to accept post and get requests.

Please give me some help to do this stuff.

My code is:

```
this.upload = function(imageURI, fileName) {
var s3URI = encodeURI("http://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/"),
        awsKey = 'AWS_KEY_HERE',
        acl = "public-read",
        secret = "SECRET_HERE",
        policy,
        policyBase64,
        signature;
policy = {
    "expiration": "2020-12-31T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "BUCKET_NAME"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
        {"acl": 'public-read'},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 524288000]
    ]
};

policyBase64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(policy));
signature = btoa(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(policyBase64, secret));
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileName;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = {
        "key": fileName,
        "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
        "acl": acl,
        "policy": policyBase64,
        "signature": signature,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    };
    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
            function(e) {
                console.log("success")
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("error")
            }, options);


}
```

For this request I have error response with `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

Regards.

Comment: Have you got the solution? Can you share it?